# Web application compiles and runs natively but not on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have made and MVC restful api using .NET Core quite a while back and have managed to successfully install it on my IIS server.

Recently I have needed to make a few updates to the program. The project no longer wanted to compile but the problem was quickly rectified by fixing some missing references. (Perhaps the .sln also got damaged?)

When I enter debug mode in Visual Studio the project runs perfectly, every function doing exactly what it needs to.

On the server, however, it seems to keep searching for a directory when I enter the URL, which seems to me that IIS isn't running the exe I compiled.

My process is as follows:

1. In Visual Studio, Build > Configuration Manager> Config > Release >  close
2. Build > Build
3. Open file explorer > naviagate to project >  bin > release > net452 > win7-x86 > copy all the contents of this directory to the server.
4. On the public server: Stop the application pool for the previous version of the web api
5. Find the previous version of the web api in the sites, under action click explore, replace the contents of this directory with what I copied from the the "bin" folder.
6. Restart the application

Now I have replaced many MVC *websites* like this in the past so I see no reason for the web api to be any different, yet somehow, whenever I open the site, I get this error:

[image: Unable to list conetents of directory]

I find this rather weird considering it should not be trying to list the directory but rather executing the application. 
The URL's I am running are correct but for argument sake here they are:

When debugging in Visual Studio:
http://localhost:10503/rest/service_name/?param=1&param=2/
(I have a "Route" configured for this)

When trying to access it on public IIS server:
http://webservices.company.co.za/appservices/rest/service_name/?param=1&param=2
"app services" is a virtual path configured in IIS

Regardless if I type the URL of a web service or if I simply type in garbage the results are the same, the browser or IIS looks for a location.

If I copy the previous bin files back to the IIS app location the service runs perfectly (without the new changes of course)

I have been struggling with this for over a week, can somebody shed some light on this, please?

Comment: Have you tried using Visual Studio for publishing to IIS? I've encountered the same error when copying files manually.

Comment: What exactly was previously in the folder before you replaced it with the .NET Core app? An ASP.NET or an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: I agree with @Houndolon.  I'd try to do one of the VS deploy methods.  Just copying the bin files seems at least suspect - very likely to cause failures.

Comment: Silly remark but maybe worth mentioning. Try assign the IIS account access to those files and folders as I have noticed permissions also go with the files themselves and it could potentially lead to a 401

Comment: If Visual Studio deployment also can not get the service up then check if AspNetCoreHandler is registered in your Service handlers and the application pool does not have a .net framework associated to it.

Comment: Have you tried with `http://webservices.company.co.za/appservices/rest/service_name?param=1&param=2 ` (i.e., you seem to have an extra "/")